# RACObserve(), RAC() - how to set a BOOL value based on an NSString

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

Being a ReactiveCocoa newbie, I'm hoping for some advice with this:

I'm trying to create a dynamic form that contains multiple Field objects parsed from an XML file.  Each Field can have muliple validation rules that will run against the Field's `NSString *value` param.

For the RAC part of the question-

inside each Field object, I want to bind `BOOL completed` to a signal that checks the Field's `*value` param against an array of rules.  So far I've gotten here with my thinking:

```
@implementation Field

self = [super init];
if (self) {

    RAC(self, completed) = [RACObserve(self, value) filter:^BOOL(NSString *fieldValue) {
        NSLog(@"%s::self.completed = %d\n", sel_getName(_cmd), self.completed);  // trying to watch the values here, with no luck 
        NSLog(@"%s::fieldValue = %@\n", sel_getName(_cmd), fieldValue);  // same here, I'd like to be able to view the `*value` here but so far no luck

        return [self validateCurrentValue]; // currently this method just checks value.length > 5 
    }];
}
return self;
```

The `*value` param has already been bound to my view model (successfully) and it gets updated each time a textfield changes.

What I'm looking for is a basic example or best-practice, the code above crashes when run so I know I'm missing something fundamental.

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-filter:` is simply passing values from `RACObserve(self, value)` through unchanged, but only if the block returns `YES`. So that means you're trying to set `completed` to values of whatever type `value` is. That's Probably Bad®.

But the good news is that you're really close!

Instead of filtering, you want to transform. You want to take every `value` and map it to something other thing. Namely whether that value passes validation. To do that, we use `-map:`:

```
RAC(self, completed) = [RACObserve(self, value) map:^(NSString *fieldValue) {
    return @([self validateCurrentValue]);    
}];
```

Comment: And will not forget past @weakify(self),@strongify(self)